# CSS - Como evitar conflitos de múltiplos arquivos?

Tags: css

### Situação

Eu tenho vários arquivos `css`, alguns meus, outros de bibliotecas.

### Duvida

- Qual o melhor meio de bloquear o `css` externo para determinados elementos?

### Exemplo

#### Efeito Atual

```css
/***** CSS EXTERNO *****/
form div{
  padding: 5px;
  clear:both;
}

/***** OUTRO CSS EXTERNO *****/
div div{
  margin: 10px;
}
div label{
  font-size: 20px;
}

/***** MEU CSS *****/
.content-form>div{
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  float:left;
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.content-form>div>label{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="content-form">
    <div>
      <label>Item 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note que aqui os css externos estão interferindo no resultado que eu desejo, para o css que eu montei.

#### Efeito Desejado

```css
.content-form>div{
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  float:left;
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.content-form>div>label{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="content-form">
    <div>
      <label>Item 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Nota

- Eu não posso remover os arquivos, pois alguns css são usados um outros lugares
- Eu não posso remover os `css` específicos, pois eles são usados em outros elementos, apenas quero inativá-lo para aquele elemento especifico.

### Tentativa atual

```css
/***** CSS EXTERNO *****/
form div{
  padding: 5px;
  clear:both;
}

/***** OUTRO CSS EXTERNO *****/
div div{
  margin: 10px;
}
div label{
  font-size: 20px;
}

/***** MEU CSS *****/
form.content-form div{
  padding:0;
  clear:none;
}

div .content-form div{
  margin:0;
}
div .content-form div label{
  font-size:inherit;
}

.content-form>div{
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  float:left;
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.content-form>div>label{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="content-form">
    <div>
      <label>Item 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note que aqui eu estou basicamente sobrescrevendo todo o css externo.

Comment: Tenta trocar a posição de inclusão deles. Isso também afeta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, mas só se for a mesma sentença tipo `file1 - div div{}`, `file2 - div div`, ai o segundo sobrescreve o primeiro, o problema é que é a especificidade que cada arquivo esta dando. `file1 - div div{}`, `file2 - form div{}` ai ele interpreta como coisas diferentes e gera um "merge", o que não é desejado.

Comment: Por qual motivo você não pode remover alguns arquivos? Não é possível também gerar um único arquivo, unindo e removendo estilos? Você não pode nem modificar os nomes? Pois a especificidade de cada elemento está muito ampla, acredito que esse seja o maior ponto negativo.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade eu determinados momentos outros elementos são renderizados e usam o mesmo css e se aplicam corretamente, contudo para o elemento que estou querende renderizar ele também se aplica e não é o que desenho, desta forma estou gerando um código de sobrescrita, contudo gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito melhor.

Comment: Eu pelo menos desconheço alguma técnica que não seja de sobrescrever quando utilizamos outro arquivo `css`, a não ser a ordem de chamada dos arquivos, como já mencionado pelo @WallaceMaxters . Nesse caso, acredito que você deve realmente criar regras que sobrescrevam as propriedades desejadas.

Comment: Apesar de não ser projetado pra isso, você pode usar o operador `!important` para dar mais enfase na regra desejada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guilherme, quando temos classes do CSS mal estruturadas e não podemos alterar a organização do mesmo, então só nos resta uma opção, criar um `Shadow DOM` e isolar o `HTML`/`CSS` de uma parte da pagina.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var root = container.createShadowRoot();

while (container.lastChild) {
  root.insertBefore(container.lastChild, root.firstChild);
}
```

```css
/***** CSS EXTERNO *****/
form div{
  padding: 5px;
  clear:both;
}

/***** OUTRO CSS EXTERNO *****/
div div{
  margin: 10px;
}
div label{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <style type="text/css">
    .content-form>div{
      border:1px solid #CCC;
      float:left;
      min-width:50px;
      min-height:10px;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .content-form>div>label{
      color:blue;
    }
  </style>
  <form class="content-form">
    <div>
      <label>Item 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Item 3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara que legal essa função, isolar o css de uma parte da página... +1

Comment: Mas ao criar essa mesma regra de `css` dentro de um arquivo que seja inicializado após o arquivo de `css` padrão, não daria o mesmo resultado?

Comment: Nosso nunca vi, muito interessante +1, por hora :D

Comment: Isso seria similar a um `iframe`?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, é um pouco mais complicado, você pode ler mais a respeito em: [Shadow DOM 101](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/).

Comment: Mas em resumo, tanto o [`Shadow DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM), quanto o [`Template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) são recursos do HTML5, você pode combinar os dois para criar `Web Components`